# Find records that have different relation [many to many]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this model:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
   ...
end
```

and this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :offers
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I want to find all offers that have relations with tag with a name on array

For example:

```
Offers1 -> Tag1, Tag2
Offers2 -> Tag2, Tag3
Offers3 -> Tag2, Tag3, Tag4

Tag1.name="test1"
Tag2.name="test2"
Tag3.name="test3"
Tag4.name="test4"
```

If i have this array `["test2","test3"]` i want to find `Offers2` and `Offers3`.

If i have this array `["test2","test3","test4"]` i want to find `Offers3`.

I hope I have explained well, thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: I tried this solution but returns all the offers that have at least one of those relations: `@offers = Offer.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: ["test2","test3","test4"]})`. For example: If i have this array ["test2","test3","test4"] find all offers.

Comment: Basically you would use `joins` with a `where` condition, the crux is that you to use an `tags.name = "test2"  AND tags.name = "test3"...` clause not IN `( "test2", "test3", "test4" )`

Comment: I missed the point that you wanted records that had all the tags. Thats why i removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best possible I could think of but its still not very efficient.

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def has_tags?(other_tags)
    tag_names = tags.loaded? ? tags.map(&:name) : tags.pluck(:name)
    (other_tags - tag_names).empty?
  end
end
```

This diffs the array to the left with the the array to the right. The result is not empty if the offer does not have all the tags.

```
names = ["test2","test3","test4"]

# take the records with any of the tag names
offers = Offer.joins(:tags).where(tag: { name: names })

# filter the offers in Ruby
offers.select { |o| o.has_tags?(names) }
```

Comment: Note that this will not work with `eager_load` since it uses a `LEFT OUTER` join instead.

Comment: In this way I have this query: `SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" INNER JOIN "offers_tags" ON "offers_tags"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "offers_tags"."tag_id" WHERE (tags.name = 'test1' AND tags.name = 'test2') ` . What if I have more than one tag returns a null array

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I'm a bit unsure as to how to construct the the condition so that it matches if it is a bigger set but still contains the desired names.

Comment: Edited, its the best I can think of. Still not really happy with it since you need  pull a bunch of data to sort it in Ruby. Unfortunatly I'm not good enough at SQL to figure out a query to pull the right set. If this remains unanswered I'll put a bounty on it since I am quite interested in how that could be done.

Comment: Thanks! When you use params "names" on has_tags function?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it does not work, I think that the error is in the "has_tags" function. "other tags" is not initialized, am I wrong? I'm sorry for too many requests

Comment: My bad, I left the argument out from the `has_tags?` method.

Comment: I managed to get a far better answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131803/sql-where-joined-set-must-contain-all-values-but-may-contain-more. The example in there is pretty much identical so it should be easy to adapt.

Comment: Thanks! This is a function:
 `def self.includes_tags(*tag_names)
      joins(:tags)
      .where(tags: { name: tag_names })
      .group('offers.id')
      .having('count(*) = ?', tag_names.size)
  end`
Query:
`SELECT "offers".* 
FROM "offers" 
INNER JOIN "offers_tags" ON "offers_tags"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" 
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "offers_tags"."tag_id" 
WHERE "tags"."name" IN ('test1', 'test2') 
GROUP BY offers.id 
HAVING count(*) = 1`
It does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  scope :with_tags, lambda do |tags = []|
    tags_sql = tags.collect { |tag| "tags.name = '#{tag}'" }.join(" AND ")
    joins(:tags).where(tags_sql)
  end
end
```

Then you could call:

```
@offers = Offer.with_tags(["tag1", "tag2"])
```

Comment: This solution don't work with two or more tags. The array of offers is null

Comment: Could you post the sql query that is being run.

Comment: `SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" INNER JOIN "offers_tags" ON "offers_tags"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "offers_tags"."tag_id" WHERE (tags.name = 'tag1' AND tags.name = 'tag2')`