# SQL where joined set must contain all values but may contain more

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, relational-division

I have three tables `offers`, `sports` and the join table `offers_sports`.

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
end

class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :offers
end
```

I want to select offers that *include* a given array of sport names. They *must* contain all of the `sports` but *may* have more.

Lets say I have these three offers:

```
light:
  - "Yoga"
  - "Bodyboarding"
medium:
  - "Yoga"
  - "Bodyboarding"
  - "Surfing"
all:
  - "Yoga"
  - "Bodyboarding"
  - "Surfing"
  - "Parasailing"
  - "Skydiving"
```

Given the array `["Bodyboarding", "Surfing"]` I would want to get `medium` and `all` but not `light`.

I have tried something along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23721658/544825) but I get zero rows in the result:

```
Offer.joins(:sports)
     .where(sports: { name: ["Bodyboarding", "Surfing"] })
     .group("sports.name")
     .having("COUNT(distinct sports.name) = 2")
```

Translated to SQL:

```
SELECT "offers".* 
FROM "offers" 
INNER JOIN "offers_sports" ON "offers_sports"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"     
INNER JOIN "sports" ON "sports"."id" = "offers_sports"."sport_id" 
  WHERE "sports"."name" IN ('Bodyboarding', 'Surfing') 
GROUP BY sports.name 
HAVING COUNT(distinct sports.name) = 2;
```

An ActiveRecord answer would be nice but I'll settle for just SQL, preferably Postgres compatible.

Data:

```
offers
======================
id | name
----------------------
1  | light
2  | medium
3  | all
4  | extreme

sports
======================
id | name
----------------------
1  | "Yoga"
2  | "Bodyboarding"
3  | "Surfing"
4  | "Parasailing"
5  | "Skydiving"

offers_sports
======================
offer_id | sport_id
----------------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 1
2        | 2
2        | 3
3        | 1
3        | 2
3        | 3
3        | 4
3        | 5
4        | 3
4        | 4
4        | 5
```

Comment: Does the SQL work?  It looks correct.

Comment: It returns 0 rows. @GordonLinoff

Comment: You're almost there: group by the "offers" fields (replace the * by explicit field names and repeat those in the group by). You're now grouping by sports.name and naturally, the distinct count of sports.name per sports.name is always 1.

Comment: @HenkKok still gives 0 rows: `SELECT offers.name, offers.id, sports.id FROM "offers" INNER JOIN "offers_sports" ON "offers_sports"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" INNER JOIN "sports" ON "sports"."id" = "offers_sports"."sport_id" WHERE "sports"."name" IN ('Bodyboarding', 'Surfing') GROUP BY offers.name, offers.id, sports.name HAVING COUNT(distinct sports.name) = 2`

Comment: That's because you still included sports.name in the group by, that column has to go from the group by; also, sports.id must be removed from the SELECT clause. If you need the offers plus the sports in the final result, first do the select on the offers (that are linked to all 2 sports) and then use that select as an inline view to join to sports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `offer.id`, not by `sports.name` (or `sports.id`):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM   sports        s
JOIN   offers_sports os ON os.sport_id = s.id
JOIN   offers        o  ON os.offer_id = o.id
WHERE  s.name IN ('Bodyboarding', 'Surfing') 
GROUP  BY o.id  -- !!
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Assuming the typical implementation:

- `offer.id` and `sports.id` are defined as primary key.
- `sports.name` is defined unique.
- `(sport_id, offer_id)` in `offers_sports` is defined unique (or PK).

You don't need `DISTINCT` in the count. And `count(*)` is even a bit cheaper, yet.

Related answer with an arsenal of possible techniques:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

---

Added by @max (the OP) - this is the above query rolled into ActiveRecord:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
  def self.includes_sports(*sport_names)
    joins(:sports)
      .where(sports: { name: sport_names })
      .group('offers.id')
      .having("count(*) = ?", sport_names.size)
  end
end
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works exactly as advertised!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is using arrays and the `array_agg` aggregate function.

```
SELECT "offers".*, array_agg("sports"."name") as spnames 
FROM "offers" 
INNER JOIN "offers_sports" ON "offers_sports"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"     
INNER JOIN "sports" ON "sports"."id" = "offers_sports"."sport_id" 
GROUP BY "offers"."id" HAVING array_agg("sports"."name")::text[] @> ARRAY['Bodyboarding','Surfing']::text[];
```

returns:

```
 id |  name  |                      spnames                      
----+--------+---------------------------------------------------
  2 | medium | {Yoga,Bodyboarding,Surfing}
  3 | all    | {Yoga,Bodyboarding,Surfing,Parasailing,Skydiving}
(2 rows)
```

The `@>` operator means that the array on the left must contain all the elements from the one on the right, but may contain more. The `spnames` column is just for show, but you can remove it safely.

There are two things you must be very mindful of with this.

1. Even with Postgres 9.4 (I haven't tried 9.5 yet) type conversion for comparing arrays is sloppy and often errors out, telling you it can't find a way to convert them to comparable values, so as you can see in the example I've manually cast both sides using `::text[]`.
2. I have no idea what the level of support for array parameters is Ruby, nor the RoR framework, so you may end-up having to manually escape the strings (if input by user) and form the array using the `ARRAY[]` syntax.

Comment: It does work and its not a bad answer - however Erwin's was much easier to integrate. You would basically need to generate the having clause as a string and bind the values to escape it. Not really hard but its still tricky to get the association loading right on this one. Thanks!