# find has_and_belongs_to_many association with multiple ids inclusive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Production Model with has_and_belongs_to_many relation on Tags.

I have an array of tag_ids = ['tag_one', 'tag_two'] and I want to find Productions who have those two tags or more.

Example :  Production with tags ['tag_one', 'tag_two', 'tag_three'] would be return but a production with tags ['tag_one', 'tag_three'] wouldn't.

What I have tried so far :

```
Production.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: ['tag_one','tag_two'] })
```

This request is not inclusive, it's returning production who have tag_one **OR** tag_two

```
Production.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: ['tag_one'] }).where(tags: { id: ['tag_two'] })
```

This one is returning an empty array, i guess it's looking for a tag who has both ids which is impossible.

If you guys have any idea on how i can solve this it would be awesome

Thanks

Comment: I asked a [very simular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131803/sql-where-joined-set-must-contain-all-values-but-may-contain-more) a while back that you can adapt for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[includes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) method is for including related records in final resultset. Here you need to filter records using associates, which can be done with [joins](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins).

Then, records should be grouped (by `id`). Since `tags` table is joined, for every record of `productions` table you could have a whole list of record's tags. And depending on your situation you could apply different conditions on that tag list.

To fetch `Production` records which have ONLY given tags and nothing else (ie records with `['tag_one']` or `['tag_one', 'tag_two', 'tag_three']` will be ignored):

```
Production.joins(:tags)
          .having("array_agg(tags.id ORDER BY tags.id ASC) = ARRAY[#{tag_ids.sort.map { |t| "'#{t}'" }.join(',')}]")
          .group('productions.id')
```

To fetch `Production` records which have EVERY of given tags (ie record with `['tag_one', 'tag_two', 'tag_three']` tags will be fetched too)

```
Production.joins(:tags)
          .where(tags: { id: tag_ids })
          .having("count(*) = #{tag_ids.count}")
          .group('productions.id')
```