# Why does group or group_by not work on this version of rails table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this rails migration with the following code

```
class CreateCertificatesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :certificates_users do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :certificate, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

In Certificate model and User model, I have `has_many :certificates_users`

This allows me to be able to add a certificate to a user's profile. 
Currently, I have 2 users, and I have added Certificate for both of them.

```
2.5.3 :010 > CertificatesUser.all
  CertificatesUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "certificates_users".* FROM "certificates_users" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CertificatesUser id: 8, user_id: 1, certificate_id: 1, expiry_date: "2020-01-14", certificate_number: "1122", renewal_date: "2019-01-14", ispublic: 1>, #<CertificatesUser id: 9, user_id: 2, certificate_id: 1, expiry_date: "2020-01-16", certificate_number: "123", renewal_date: "2019-01-16", ispublic: 1>, #<CertificatesUser id: 10, user_id: 2, certificate_id: 2, expiry_date: "2019-02-28", certificate_number: "123", renewal_date: "2019-01-16", ispublic: 1>]>
```

Here is the *certificates_users* table for clarity.

```
id | user_id | certificate_id | ...
---+---------+----------------+----
 8 |       1 |              1 |
 9 |       2 |              1 |
10 |       2 |              2 |
```

One User has 2 certificates and the other has one.

My goal is to be able to list out Users who have a certain type of certificate.

1. List out users who have a certificate with the id of 1 (should list out both users). - Dropdown 1
2. List out only users who have both certificates with the id of 1 and certificate with the id of 2 (should list out only 1 user). - Dropdown 2
3. When any of this user is selected from their separate dropdowns list out their certificate in another dropdown.

I have tried to use `group` and `group_by` to achieve this result but it did not work. The idea is that I am trying to group the `CertificatesUser` by `user_id` but that didn't work. It returned this error:

```
2.5.3 :011 > CertificatesUser.group_by(&:user_id)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):11
NoMethodError (undefined method `group_by' for #<Class:0x00007fa8dda7c668>)
Did you mean?  group
```

Then I used `group` method and got this:

```
2.5.3 :012 > CertificatesUser.group('users.id')
  CertificatesUser Load (7.2ms)  SELECT  "certificates_users".* FROM "certificates_users" GROUP BY users.id LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users")
LINE 1: ...cates_users".* FROM "certificates_users" GROUP BY users.id L...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "certificates_users".* FROM "certificates_users" GROUP BY users.id LIMIT $1
```

Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: `#group` is a query method that creates a SQL GROUP BY clause. `#group_by` on the other hand is from the [enumerable mixin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html) and iterates through a collection in Ruby. You can't call `.group_by` on a model class as its not a collection. You would need to do `CertificatesUser.all.group_by(&:user_id)`. But that would be really inefficient compared to using `#group`.

Comment: "List out only users who have both certificates with the id of 1 and certificate with the id of 2 (should list out only 1 user)." This can be done by using something likle `Certificate.joins(:certificate_users).where(certificate_user: { user_id: [1, 2] }).having('count(*) = 2').group('certificates.id')` on Postgres but this really is a whole question on its own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131803/sql-where-joined-set-must-contain-all-values-but-may-contain-more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

I fail to see why you need to group anything at all. I would solve this issue with the use of sub-queries.

```rb
certificate_1_user_ids = CertificatesUser.select(:user_id).where(certificate_id: 1)
certificate_2_user_ids = CertificatesUser.select(:user_id).where(certificate_id: 2)

# List out users who have a certificate with the id of 1.
users_with_certificate_1 = User.where(id: certificate_1_user_ids)

# List out only users who have both certificates with the
#   id of 1 and certificate with the id of 2.
users_with_certificate_1_and_2 = User.where(id: certificate_1_user_ids)
                                     .where(id: certificate_2_user_ids)
```

The last question might be worth a separate question. However I will mention that you can do the following.

```rb
# with the following associations present in app/models/user.rb
has_many :certificates_users
has_many :certificates, through: :certificates_users

# you can eager load associations to avoid the 1+N problem
users.includes(:certificates).each do |user|
  # do stuff with user

  user.certificates.each do |certificate|
    # do stuff with certificate
  end
end
```

## Dynamic Certificate IDs

In the comments you asked how to make this answer work for dynamic certificate IDs. For the answer given above this can be done in the following way.

```rb
certificate_ids = [1, 2]

users = certificate_ids.reduce(User) do |scope, certificate_id|
  user_ids = CertificatesUser.select(:user_id).where(certificate_id: certificate_id)
  scope.where(id: user_ids)
end
```

The resulting query should look something like this (for MySQL).

```sql
SELECT `users`.*
FROM `users`
WHERE
  `users`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `certificates_users`.`user_id`
    FROM `certificates_users`
    WHERE `certificates_users`.`certificate_id` = 1
  )
  AND `users`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `certificates_users`.`user_id`
    FROM `certificates_users`
    WHERE `certificates_users`.`certificate_id` = 2
  )
```

## Optimizing the Query

Although the above example shows us how to make the whole thing dynamic. Doing this for larger amounts of certificate IDs doesn't produce the most efficient query.

Another way of approaching this does involve grouping and is a slightly more difficult to execute. This involves searching through the *certificates_users* table for records that match one of the given IDs. Then count the amount of records for each user. If the amount of records equals the amount of certificate IDs given it means that an user has all those certificates.

### Prerequisites

This method does however come with prerequisites.

- **The combination of *user_id* and *certificate_id* must be unique in the *certificates_users* table.** You can make sure that this is the case by placing an unique constraint over those columns.

  ```rb
  add_index :certificates_users, %i[user_id certificate_id], unique: true
  ```
- Another optional recommendation is that the columns *user_id* and *certificate_id* in the *certificates_users* table cannot be `NULL`. You can make sure this is the case by creating the columns using

  ```
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true, null: false
  ```

  or by changing the column using

  ```
  change_column_null :certificates_users, :user_id, false
  ```

  Of course the above example must be repeated for the *certificate_id* column as well.

### Optimization

With the prerequisites out of the way, lets have a look at this solution.

```rb
certificates_users = CertificatesUser.arel_table
certificate_ids = [1, 2]

users = User.joins(:certificates_users)
            .where(certificate_users: { certificate_id: certificate_ids })
            .group(:id)
            .having(certificates_users[:id].count.eq(certificate_ids.size))

# Nested sections in a where always require the table name, not the
#   association name. Here is an example that makes it more clear.
#
#     Post.joins(:user).where(users: { is_admin: true })
#                  ^           ^- table name
#                  +-- association name
```

The above example should produce the following query (for MySQL).

```sql
SELECT `users`.*
FROM `users`
  INNER JOIN `certificates_users`
    ON `users`.`id` = `certificates_users`.`user_id`
WHERE `certificates_users`.`certificate_id` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(`certificates_users`.`id`) = 2
```

When increasing the `certificate_ids` array the query stays the same, other than the following two parts.

- `IN (1, 2)` becomes `IN (1, 2, 4, 7, 8)`
- `COUNT(...) = 2` becomes `COUNT(...) = 5`

## References

Most of the code used speaks for itself. If you're not yet familiar with `reduce` I recommend taking a look at the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). Since this method is present in a lot of other programming languages. It's a great tool to have in your arsenal.

The *arel* gem API isn't really meant for use outside of the internals of Rails. For this reason it's documentation is pretty bad. However you can find most of the methods used [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/Attributes/Attribute).

Comment: Wow I’m convinced that this will work even without trying it out yet. I’ll give it a shot and drop a comment once I get it to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since `users_with_certificate_1_and_2` is just a subset of `users_with_certificate_1` you could also do `users_with_certificate_1_and_2 = users_with_certificate_1.where(id: certificate_2_user_ids)`. Use whatever has your preference.

Comment: @mayorsanmayor I've updated the answer to include a dynamic certificate IDs section.

Comment: Thanks for the update on your answer @Johan I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to be able to list out Users who have a certain type of certificate.

You can do it using `joins`:

```
certificate_ids = [1,2] # or anything other ids
User.joins(:certificates_users).where('certificates_users.certificate_id' => certificate_ids)
```

Regarding `group` and `group_by`.

`group_by` can be called on [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), so you cannot call it on an AR model directly. You could do it like that:

```
CertificatesUser.all.group_by(&:user_id)
```

but it's terribly inefficient - you load the whole table to memory.

To use `group` you need to specify a correct column name. You use `users.id` and your `certificates_users` has no such field. You can probably use

```
CertificatesUser.group('user_id')
```

Comment: Even better would be to use a symbol if possible inside the *group* method. When using a string it will be seen as SQL and placed inside the resulting query. When using a symbol an attribute is assumed and it will be replaced with the namespaced version (`\`certificates_users\`.\`user_id\`` for MySQL for example). This approach is less likely to have name collisions. This would happen when joining two tables that both have the same column name.

Comment: @mrzasa thanks for your answer. This didn't work `User.joins(:certificates_users).where('certificate_users.certificate_id' => certificate_ids)`. 
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):14
NameError (undefined local variable or method `certificate_ids' for main:Object)
`

Comment: what was the result?

Comment: added in the comment above.

Comment: well you need to define `certificate_ids` variable. See edited version of the post.

Comment: still didn't work @mrzasa
  `User Load (230.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "certificates_users" ON "certificates_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "certificate_users"."certificate_id" IN ($1, $2) LIMIT $3  [["certificate_id", 1], ["certificate_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "certificate_users")
LINE 1: ...ertificates_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "certifica...`

Comment: fixed a typo in a table name, try now