# How to use an ActiveRecord query to find records based on association tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a database with these current values:

```
User
id | name
1  | Sara
2  | Alice
3  | Samantha

UserTag
id | user_id | label      | value
1  | 1       | hair_color | blonde
2  | 1       | polite     | no

3  | 2       | hair_color | brunette
4  | 2       | polite     | yes

5  | 3       | hair_color | brunette
6  | 3       | polite     | no
```

And the associated models:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags,
    class_name: 'UserTag',
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    dependent: :destroy,
    inverse_of: :user
end

class UserTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :tags, touch: true
end
```

I want to find all the "brunette" users who are "not polite", basically, "Samantha".  I tried the following without success:

```rb
# Returns 0
User.joins(:tags)
.where(user_tags: { label: 'hair_color', value: 'brunette' })
.where(user_tags: { label: 'polite', value: 'no' })
.count
```

```
# .to_sql
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"user_tags\" ON \"user_tags\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE \"user_tags\".\"label\" = 'hair_color' AND \"user_tags\".\"value\" = 'brunette' AND \"user_tags\".\"label\" = 'polite' AND \"user_tags\".\"value\" = 'no'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result are you getting? Seems correct to me. You can call `.to_sql` instead of `.count` to see the actual query.

Comment: I added the .to_sql -- I kinda see why this is not working (the query is not "clustered" with ()) but I have no clue how to explain it / fix it.

Comment: The issue here is that `WHERE user_tags.value = "brunette" AND user_tags.value = 'no'` will only return rows for which both conditions are true, not rows with two joined entities.  You have to use having with a count of the joined rows. The answer here depends on the db. I asked a question a while back for postgres that got pretty good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131803/sql-where-joined-set-must-contain-all-values-but-may-contain-more

Comment: It seems your user_tags table isn't correctly or completely normalized. A `where` filter will _throw out_ those rows with label other than "hair_color" and value "brunette", so you can't re-apply a filter for those with label "polite" and value "no".

Comment: Additionally what you are doing here is not tagging at all. Its just a [EAV table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) in disguise. Tags just have a single value. Like for example on stackoverflow you can attach the tags `ruby`, `ruby-on-rails`. In your example the equivilent would be the tags `blonde`, `brunette`, `polite` and `impolite`.

Comment: @max I'm using Postgres, would you mind sharing an example? Thanks for the EAV thingy :)

Comment: For a simple tagging solution, you could also look at gem [act_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) (why reinvent the wheel?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to build a tag system and not just a [EAV monstrosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) this is how you do it.

Start by creating a normalised tags table and a user_tags join table:

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name, unique: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUserTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_tags do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :tag, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index [:user_id, :tag_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Then setup the associations:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tags
  has_many :users, through: :user_tags
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class UserTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag
  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: :user_id
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :user_tags
end
```

To query a user with multiple tags you can then do:

```
User.joins(:tags)
    .where(tags: { name: ['Brunette', 'Impolite'] } )
    .group('users.id')
    .having('count(*) = 2')
```

You could also just roll this into a class method:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :user_tags

  def self.with_tags(*tags)
    raise ArgumentError, 'must pass more than one tag' if tags.none?
    self.joins(:tags)
        .where(tags: { name: tags } )
        .group('users.id')
        .having('count(*) = ?', tags.length)
  end
end
```

Comment: Beware however that when you use `.group` with `.count` you get a hash with the counts per group so `User.joins(:tags).group(:id).count` will give you `{2=>2, 1=>2, 3=>2}` and not an integer as you might expect.